# Implementing Geographic Web Service?

Tags: postgis, web-service, php

I was told to implement a web service which, given 2 inputs (street name, cross street name) the output is the crossing geographical coordinates.

What is the best way i should go?

Is there a standard for Geographical Web Services that queries a database?

Are there same similar examples? (I haven't found anyone)

We use PHP, and a Postgres database with Postgis.

I have developed a solution whith nusoap and xml but I really don't know if 
this is a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a PostGIS RESTful Web Service Framework [here](http://geojason.info/google-vector-layers/demos/postgis-restful-web-service-framework/) for google-map but you can use its result.
you can check out whether it works for you or not...

the result is sth like this :

> {"total_rows":"20","rows":[{"row":{"gid":"1","name":"Main
>   Library","address":"310 N. Tryon
>   St","city":"Charlotte","geojson":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.840724581696904,35.228864793191491]}}},{"row":{"gid":"3","name":"Beatties
>   Ford Road Branch","address":"2412 Beatties Ford
>   Rd","city":"Charlotte","geojson":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.853981238642987,35.267446222268148]}}},{"row":{"gid":"5","name":"Cornelius
>   Branch","address":"21216 Catawba
>   Av","city":"Cornelius","geojson":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.862416068045874,35.482669302763846]}}}]}

[image: rest]